# How to define a button and a function inside js (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapbox

- I am using MapBox to render a map. I have made a `onClick` function wherein when clicked on the map it shows the geocode information shown in the screenshot below through api.

[image]

- Now what I want is to have a button below the table and when click on it I want it to execute a particular function, I have defined it but when clicked on it says `Function is not defined`
- Code

```
map.current.on('click', function(e) {

        var coordinates = e.lngLat;
        var lng = coordinates.lng;
        var lat = coordinates.lat;
        console.log(lat);
        console.log(lng);
        var d = fetch("https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/" + lng + "," + lat + ".json?access_token={token_value}").then(response => response.json()).then(function(data) {
          console.log(data)
          var str = "<table border='1'><tr><td><center>Title</center></td><td><center>Content</center></td></tr>"
          for (let i in data["features"]) {
            str = str + "<tr><td style='padding:5px'>" + data["features"][i]["place_type"][0] + "</td><td style='padding:5px'>" + data["features"][i]["place_name"] + "</td></tr>"

          }

          str = str + "</table>"
          
          // button
          str = str + "<button onClick={myFunction}>Save</button>"

          function myFunction() {
            console.log('Saved pressed');
          }
          
          new mapboxgl.Popup()
            .setLngLat(coordinates)
            .setHTML(str)
            .addTo(map.current)
        });
        console.log(d);
      });
```

Comment: The string might not be interpreted as react, I'm guessing it's just normal HTML.  Try <button onclick={myFunction()} instead?  `myFunction` may also need to be defined in the outermost scope - outside of any classes or functions

Comment: @IrkenInvader I have tried ```myFunction()``` it doesn't work

Comment: Did you try to move your function up in the scope as suggested too?

Comment: @akds Yes I did

Answer (score 0):

Fix code as below

```
// button
str += `<button onclick="myFunction()"}>Save</button>`;
```

Comment: Getting the error as ```Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input```

Comment: Oh sorry I edited my answer. Try it again.

Comment: I had added the ```+=``` , but still the same error.

Comment: Does it render well without onClick myFunction?

Comment: The issue is not in rendering. When I click on the button, instead of printing in the console as mentioned in the function, it just gives error.

Comment: Hey I updated my answer! It'll work!

Comment: When onClicked getting the error as ```map:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick```.

Comment: move your myFunction code outside of map.current.on('click', function(e) {}. JavaScript make a variable object at creating context phase but when you call the myFunction, map.current.onClick function is over. So inside of map.current.onClick variables and functions aren't valid. it's like expired. So, you should move myFunction code out of it and make as global variable.

Comment: I did tried moving it outside the function but still the same error is there.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess the button (and the function name defined for it) are created with a different scope than where you have defined your function. One of these might work:

1. Define your function as `const myFunction = () => console.log("saved pressed")`.
2. Try referencing your function as `this.myFunction`

Comment: It is not giving any output nor any error, tried debugging but the same.

Comment: I would try inspecting the element with the browser and make sure something is actually defined as the onClick property for the button. Also, not a great solution, but you could define your javascript inline with the button html. `<button onclick={console.log("hello world")}>Save</button>`

Comment: Tried inspecting it does show the function, but for now getting the error as ```Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input```. For now I have defined the function in another js file and imported it in the main js file.